How do I export a certain industry data from alienvault?
I want to export let's say manufacturing and energy and also semiconductor industry sectors in alienvault. I already have the API key for alienvault , how would I write the script to pull out raw data from eg
Manufacturing industry https://otx.alienvault.com/industry/Manufacturing and export it into a csv format?
Searched up multiple code sources and tools already but none of them works. Especially the API endpoint provided by alienvault itself doesn't seem to provide an option to pull out only a certain industry
Tried source codes online and on GitHub but to no avail.
